# Launch C# .Net Application from C++

Tags: c#, c++, c#-2.0

Is it possible to launch a C#.Net (2.0) application from an application written in C++???

Thanks,

EDIT:
Cool - so I just have to know where the app is:

```
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\MyApp -L -S"));
CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can launch any EXE using [CreatePocess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) API. ( including C#.Net)

Comment: So the fact that it is a .Net app is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, These APIs allow you to launch any EXEs

Answer (score 4):

Yes - for example using `system` function or [`CreateProcess` \ `CreateProcessW` \ `CreateProcessA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx)  [or `fork`+ `exex`if you use *nix + mono]

Comment: Do you know if this is a blocking function - will my app hang?