# Launch .NET application from another folder

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Here: [Launch C# .Net Application from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843248/launch-c-sharp-net-application-from-c) they say it's possible to launch a .NET application using `CreateProcess`.
I can't.

Even from the command prompt (Windows 10) I can run my C# application only if I `cd` to the exe folder.

I've added that folder to the `PATH` env var, so my C++ application can run it without know where it actually is. But as said it doesn't run.

Trying with the command prompt it just says "This application cannot be started".

Is there something more I have to do?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I apologize, but my question is how to launch a C# application from another folder, i.e. using command prompt. What code should I post?

Comment: Dumb question, but do you actually have the right version of .NET installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This application could not be started." Only when the file is in system32 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214983/this-application-could-not-be-started-only-when-the-file-is-in-system32-direc)

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but could be something that's impacting you.

Comment: Exactly, you cannot start the application from a windows/* directory (at least with Windows 10).